# My java program compiled but won't run

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My java program compiles but does not return anything when I try to run it. I'm working on an assignment where I am using multiple methods and I'm not sure if I did something wrong with the methods that may have had an effect on the program not running at all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CombatCalculatorExpansion1{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int monstersHealth = 100;
        int monsterAttackpower = 0;
        String monstersName;
        int xp;
        int yourHealth = 0;
        int yourAttackpower = 0;
        int magicPower = 0;
        int magicPoints = 0;
        int statPoints = 20;
    }
    public static void createHero(){

        int yourHealth = 0;
        int yourAttackpower = 0;
        int magicPower = 0;
        int magicPoints = 0;
        int statPoints = 20;    

        boolean loopControl = true;
            while (loopControl){


         System.out.println("***************************");
         System.out.println("Health: " + yourHealth);
         System.out.println("Attack: " + yourAttackpower);
         System.out.println("Magic: " + magicPower);
         System.out.println("***************************");
         System.out.println("5.) +10 Health");
         System.out.println("6.) +1 Attack");
         System.out.println("7.) +3 Magic");
         System.out.println("You have 20 points to spend: " + statPoints);
         System.out.println("***************************");

            int choice;
            Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = inputReader.nextInt();

            if(choice == 5){
                yourHealth = yourHealth + 10;
                statPoints = statPoints - 1;
            } else if(choice == 6){
                yourAttackpower = yourAttackpower + 1;
                statPoints = statPoints - 1;
            } else if(choice == 7){
                magicPower = magicPower + 3;
                statPoints = statPoints - 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("I don't understand that command.");
            } if(statPoints <= 0){
                loopControl = false;
                System.out.println("You don't have any stat points left to spend.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void runCombat(){

        int monstersHealth = 100;
        int monsterAttackpower = 0;
        String monstersName;
        int xp;
        int yourHealth = 0;
        int yourAttackpower = 0;
        int magicPower = 0;
        int magicPoints = 0;
        int statPoints = 20;

        boolean loopControl = true;
            while (loopControl){

            System.out.println("Combat Options");

            System.out.println("1.) Sword Attack");
            System.out.println("2.) Cast Spell");
            System.out.println("3.) Charge Mana");
            System.out.println("4.) Run Away");
            System.out.println("What Action do you want to perform?");

            int choice;
            Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = inputReader.nextInt();

            if(choice == 1){
                monstersHealth = monstersHealth - yourAttackpower;
                System.out.println("You strike the goblin with your sword for 12 damage!");
                System.out.println(monstersHealth + " health remaining");
            } else if (choice == 2){
                if(magicPower >= 3){ 
                System.out.println("You cast the weaken spell on the monster.");
                monstersHealth = monstersHealth / 2;
                } else
                System.out.println("You don't have enough mana.");
                System.out.println(monstersHealth + " health remaining");
            } else if (choice == 3){
                magicPower = magicPower + 1;
                System.out.println("You focus and charge your magic power.");

            } else if (choice == 4){

                loopControl = false;
                System.out.println("You run away!");
            } else if (choice >= 8){
                System.out.println("I don't understand that command.");
            }
            if(monstersHealth <= 0){
               loopControl = false;
               System.out.println("You defeated the goblin!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createMonster(){

        int monstersHealth = 100;
        int monsterAttackpower = 0;
        String monstersName;
        int xp;

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
        if (randomNumber == 0){
            monstersName = "Goblin";
            monstersHealth = 75 + randomGenerator.nextInt(24);
            monsterAttackpower = 8 + randomGenerator.nextInt(4);
            xp = 1;
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 1){
            monstersName = "Orc";
            monstersHealth = 100 + randomGenerator.nextInt(24);
            monsterAttackpower = 12 + randomGenerator.nextInt(4);
            xp = 3;
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 2){
            monstersName = "Troll";
            monstersHealth = 150 + randomGenerator.nextInt(49);
            monsterAttackpower = 15 + randomGenerator.nextInt(4);
            xp = 5;

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: in its main function does not call any method

Comment: What does it mean when it does not run.  Any error message?  Any debugging attempts?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

As I can see there is no method call in your main method try to call your static method within main method like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        int monstersHealth = 100;
        int monsterAttackpower = 0;
        String monstersName;
        int xp;
        int yourHealth = 0;
        int yourAttackpower = 0;
        int magicPower = 0;
        int magicPoints = 0;
        int statPoints = 20;
        createHero();
        createMonster();
        runCombat();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any of the method in the main function. Thus it is just creating the variables you have declared in main and returns without giving any output.

You need to create flow in the main function

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int monstersHealth = 100;
    int monsterAttackpower = 0;
    String monstersName;
    int xp;
    int yourHealth = 0;
    int yourAttackpower = 0;
    int magicPower = 0;
    int magicPoints = 0;
    int statPoints = 20;
    createHero();
    runCombat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya you are not calling any method, and the java should not be used by this way!!
for your case there is no use of initialing the variable in the main method you can call the function in the main method(according to me its beater if you call the function in the constructor instead of calling those in main method and use the variable as instance variable of the class so u can use those within different methods).

```
public CombatCalculatorExpansion1{
    createHero();
    createMonster();
    runCombat();
}
```